# What modifiers should a cached hashcode field have?

Tags: java, multithreading, caching, serialization

Given an immutable object, it sometimes makes sense to cache its hashcode. Below is an example.

*In the example, I realize that caching is more expensive than just recalculating the hashCode.*

```
  public class ImmutableObject{
    final int immutableField1;
    final String immutableField2;

    //volatile? transient? WeakReference?
    private Integer cachedHashCode = null; 

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
      Integer ret=cachedHashCode;
      if(ret == null) {
        ret = immutableField1;
        ret = 31 * ret + immutableField2.hashCode();
      }
      cachedHashCode = ret;
      return ret;
    }
    // constructor, equals, other methods...

  }
```

What modifiers does `cachedHashCode` need?

- Volatile: Effective Java recommends using the volatile modifier here ([how caching hashcode works in Java as suggested by Joshua Bloch in effective java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18473071/how-caching-hashcode-works-in-java-as-suggested-by-joshua-bloch-in-effective-jav)). As the class is immutable, under what conditions would non-strict execution ordering be dangerous? Is it solely to prevent redundant calculation of the hashCode?
- Transient: If the hashcode is derived it is almost certainly cheaper to recalculate it than to serialize/deserialize it. Under what conditions would you want to serialize a hashcode?
- WeakReference: If the class only has a couple fields, yet hashCode caching is still (somehow) worthwhile, the cached hashcode may add significantly to the memory footprint of each object. Should the cache then be a WeakReference? Will a WeakReference always take up at least as much space as the cached int?

Comment: Look at `String` source code as a best practice. Its cached `hash` is neither volatile, transient nor weakly referenced.

Answer (score 0):

volatile:

Yes. This ensures that, after the assignment with a value, it is written to the memory and all other threads of your program will see it. Without volatile or a synchronized block there is no guarantee that the written value is visible by others. This magic is defined within the Java Memory Model.

transient:

Yes. However, makes only sense for classes marked as serializable. You never want to serialize something that is easy to recalculate. Maybe only if recaluculation takes a lot of effort, it could make sense. This is the typical space/time tradeoff decision.

WeakReference:

No. This adds more overhead. If you want to safe memory change to an int value. Add an extra flag or define a special number, for the "needs calculation" purpose.